# If $\gcd(|G:U|,|G:V|)=1$ for group $G$ and subgroup $U,V$ show $G=UV$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $U,V$ subgroup of G with $|G:U|,|G:V|<\infty$. Also  $\gcd(|G:U|,|G:V|)=1$. Show that $G=UV$.

Please help to proceed with this question , first step where I get stuck is whether I can conclude G finite or not also I think I have to show $\gcd(|U|,|V|)=1$ which implies $U\cap V =\varnothing$ thus $G=UV$ .

But I don't know how to proceed .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434802/product-of-two-subgroups-the-whole-group

Answer (score 1):

There is a well defined map from $UV/U$ (i.e. the set of all right cosets $Uv$, $v\in V$) to $V/(U\cap V)$ which sends $Uv$ to $(U\cap V)v$. Therefore $|V:U\cap V|\le |G:U|$. Similarly $|U:U\cap V|\le |G:V|$.Also  $|G:U\cap V|=|G:V||V:U\cap V|=|G:U||U:U\cap V|$. Hence $|G:U|$ divides $|G:V||V:U\cap V|$. Since $|G:V|$ and $|G:U|$ are coprime, $|G:U|$ divides $|V:U\cap V|$. Hence $|G:U|=|V:U\cap V|$.

That implies that the number of cosets $Uv$ in $UV$ is $|G:U|$. Hence $G=UV$.