# Zappa-Szép product of free Lie algebras

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras

There is a perfect description for Zappa-Szép product of groups in [Has this "generalized semidirect product" been studied?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107781/has-this-generalized-semidirect-product-been-studied) . Has it been studied for free Lie algebras?

I note that, the Zappa-Szép product of Lie algebras is defined as follows:
Let $A$ and $B$ be Lie algebras. A derivatively knitted pair of representations
$(α, β)$ for $(A, B)$ are Lie algebra homomorphisms $ \alpha: A \to \operatorname{End}(B) $ and $ \beta: B \to \operatorname{End}(A)$ such that:

$ α(a)[b_{1}, b_{2}] = [α(a)b_{1}, b_{2}] + [b_{1}, α(a)b_{2}]- α(β(b_{1})a)b_{2} - α(β(b_{2})a)b_{1}$

$β(b)[a_{1}, a_{2}] = [β(b)a_{1}, a_{2}] + [a_{1}, β(b)a_{2}] -β(α(a_{1})b)a_{2} -β(α(a_{2})b)a_{1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, yes. There is a wonderful quote of [Matt Brin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406044.pdf):

> "It turns out that the Zappa-Szép product has the remarkable property that it seems to require no hypotheses at all. Group-like properties such as associativity, fullness of the multiplication, identities, and inverses can be assumed or removed at random and the Zappa-Szép product can still be discussed and used at some level."

For a concrete starting point, see short [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9204220.pdf)* on "knit products" of *graded* Lie algebras.

*Peter W. Michor, *Knit Products of Graded Lie Algebras and Groups*, Proceedings of the Winter School on Geometry and Physics, Srni 1988
Suppl. Rendiconti Circolo Matematico di Palermo,
Ser. II, 22 (1989), 171–175

Comment: Nice article by Peter Michor.